# Is it safe to switch from dalvik to art runtime?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, htc-one, dalvik, art

How can I tell if it would be safe?

I am running ViperOne 7.0.1 on an HTC One m7.

Comment: Why would you switch anyway? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Higher efficiency mostly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my Xperia M, running the latest nightly CM, it always causes trouble (every 10 seconds an app crashes), so I occasionally try it (*Is it working yet? - No, well, I guess it's time to switch back*), but I never use it - others say it's working fine for them. If you are able to switch to ART, I assume you are rooted and have a custom ROM installed, so you are also able to make a **full backup from the recovery**. You can try it, but **make a Nandroid backup first, as it could screw up everything to the point you won't be able to switch back from inside Android.** I'll say this again: **switching to ART is NOT safe! Always do a full backup from the recovery before you try it!**

On the first boot with ART, it's going to take **a lot** of time to compile everything, be patient. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is. If your apps are crashing, try to reinstall your ROM and wipe your cache. Normally it shouldn't throw crashes